# $f(r)$ vs. $f(\mathbf{r})$

Tags: functions

How different is $f(r)$ from $f(\mathbf{r})$?

If I had $f$ representing some volume charge density, how can I understand which one represents spherically symmetry?

I know the question appears vague, however, there seems to be a convention in how we describe a radial function.

Comment: Not sur sure what you are asking but usually bold variables represent vectors.

Comment: $f(r)$ does not depend on angular coordinates, only on radius. $f(\mathbf r)$ is the vector form, that might or might not be spherically symmetric.